# Media Queries issue with mobile landscape mode

Tags: html, css, mobile, landscape

i am making a new portfolio for myself and i want it to work across all platforms..

i have got it working on desktop, mobile portrait, ipad portrait and ipad landscape, all with different media queries set up..

however when i load the page on my android in landscape it does this :
* loads up the desktop version
* zooms right in rather than fitting to the screen

i would really want the phone landscape to load up the tablet landscape view as the screen sizes would be similar, but everything ive tried has no effect on it at all..

can check my code over at: [www.stuffmadeby.me/test](http://www.stuffmadeby.me/test)

Comment: Add some relevant code to this question, not just a link, and you might get some more attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking your code, the only media-query for landscape is `(min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px)`, are you sure the width of your android device isn't to small or too big ?

Comment: hi i figured it out by changing the widths and heights.. went back to basics, thanks for help :)